# LDAP attribute : olcDbURI

Tags: server, ldap, openldap

I have to migrate an openldap server, so the technician gave me the entire openldap folder contained in /etc/openldap/

But when I try a **slaptest -u**, I have an error from two files like *olcDataBase{3}* and 4 which contain a line : ***olcDbURI: "ldap://an03"***

And that returns Unknow Attribute.

I have exactly the same folder (/etc/openldap/) than the old server, and it works great on the old

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Same schemas? Same version of OpenLDAP?

Comment: Yep same schema because they're include in the folder. Almost same version but both are in 2.4.X

Comment: Same schemas *loaded*?

Comment: Yes, they are all included in the cn config module file